# If I only know some information about a credit card, what's a rough probability of collisions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given:

A credit card number is 16 digits long, of which the last one is a checksum [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

Let's say I have the following information:

- A: First 6 digits
- B: Last 4 digits
- C: Expiry month + year

**If I have two identical informations A+B+C, what is the approximate probability that they belong to the same card?**

If we didn't have the Luhn algorithm for the last digit, then the probability is basically 10^6, am I right?

Can we approximate the probability of this collision taking into account the checksum digit?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I assume (possibly incorrectly) that credit card numbers are far from random, so you'd have to know something about the way in which they were generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the card numbers are random, the checksum can be used to determine at best one other digit. With Luhn's algorithm (or any useful algorithm), this is possible to do, once you know the other 14. But you would still need 14 digits to accomplish it. The checksum can only distinguish between 10 cases, but if you don't know 2 digits, there are 100 possible values to distinguish. The checksum cannot accomplish this, no matter how it is generated.

So the checksum algorithm will break your list of $10^6$ possibilities for the remaining digits into ten lists of average size $10^5$. (For Luhn's and pretty much any other useful algorithm, the lists will all be of size $10^5$ exactly. But it is easy to come up with algorithms for which this is not the case. For example, if the "checksum" is always 2, you get one list of $10^6$ card numbers, and nine lists of $0$ card numbers.) The checksum value will pick which of these lists the card number falls in, but it can give no more information than that. Thus the best you can expect is to reduce the probability of a collision to $10^5$.